# How to create a multi select drop down in Laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel-4

I have a problem in creating multi select drop down using `Laravel 4.2`.

My multi select looks as below

```
{{Form::label('district_id','District')}}
<?php $data=array(''=>'Select');?>
{{Form::select('district_id[]',$data,'',array('id'=>'district_id','multipart'=>t
rue))}}
```

I populate the options using jQuery ajax. I do get the drop down values exactly as I want. But I am not able to make the drop down as multi select drop down.

Answer (score 1):

If everything is working properly, instead of doing

```
'multipart' => true
```

replace with

```
'multiple' => true
```

Your final code

```
{{ Form::select('district_id[]', $data, null, array('id' => 'district_id', 'multiple' => true)) }}
```

The data will be in the form of array, so in your controller you have to use foreach

```
foreach(Input::get('district_id') as $district_id)
{
    echo $district_id.'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think below code is useful for you for Multi Select DropDown

```
  $userList =  array('L' => 'Large', 'S' => 'Small');

   {{Form::select('district_id[]',  [null=>Lang::get('messages.select')]+$userList ,'L', array( 'multiple'=>"multiple")) }}
```

Comment: what s happen please tell me what issue you are facing userlist value declared in controller share with view then u get

Comment: I just want to make the above drop down as multi select. I tried the code which u gave me..After selecting more than one option i try to echo the value of the drop down.. It just shows the one which i selected last @vipul

Comment: i do get the array but with only the last option selected not all the ones which i select @vipul